# How to detect finger moves in or out my customized UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a customized UIView

`@interface EColumn : UIView`

I have many instances of this EColumn in it's super view.

How can i detect when the finger hold and moves in the area of this UIView, and when it move out.

I don't mean a tap Gesture, i can detect tap  Gesture by using this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(taped:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@implementation EColumn

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *view = [self touchedViewWithTouches:touches andEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"%@",view);
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *view = [self touchedViewWithTouches:touches andEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"%@",view);
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *view = [self touchedViewWithTouches:touches andEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"%@",view);
}

- (UIView *)touchedViewWithTouches:(NSSet *)touches andEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    UIView *touchedView;

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
    {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, touchLocation))
        {
            touchedView = view;
            break;
        }
    }

    return touchedView;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the finger hold for specific time with the **UILongPressGestureRecognizer** . For this, you can also specify *minimumPressDuration* and *numberOfTouchesRequired*

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = 
         [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
         initWithTarget:self 
         action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
    longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 3;
    longPressRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
```

For detecting moves, you can use **UIPanGestureRecognizer**

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```